# AndEngine sprites are locked when setting velocity after collision in onManagedUpdate method

Tags: android, andengine

I have to create a game in which there is one player sprite and several(approx 30) other sprites who moves randomly on the screen without colliding within themselves. I have problem in avoiding collision, since when detecting collision all the moving sprites are locked.
Below is my code..In my code I have created two classes one is `MainActivity`( This is the main class which extends `BaseGameActivity` and creates approx 30 `AnimatedSprites` using the `NewSprite` class and contains a static array list 'playerSprite' of NewSprite objects(approx 30 objects created randomly) and the second is `NewSprite`( which extends `AnimatedSprite` and overloads the method `onManagedUpdate()` to prevent these moving `AnimatedSprites` from going offscreen and collision between them.)

I have only shown `NewSprite` class..

```
public class NewSprite extends AnimatedSprite{
public PhysicsHandler physicsHandler;
Random randPos;

public NewSprite(final float pX, final float pY, final ITiledTextureRegio pTiledTextureRegion, final VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager) {
    super(pX, pY, pTiledTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);


    randPos = new Random();
    float x1;
    float y1;
    while((x1 = randPos.nextFloat()) < 0.8f);
    while((y1 = randPos.nextFloat()) < 0.8f);
    if(randPos.nextInt() % 2 == 0)
        x1 *= -1;
    if(randPos.nextInt() % 2 == 0)
        y1 *= -1;

    physicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(this);
    this.registerUpdateHandler(physicsHandler);

    physicsHandler.setVelocity(x1 * 100, y1 * 100);
}

@Override
protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(this.mX < 0){
        this.move++;
        float x2,y2;
        while((x2 = randPos.nextFloat()) < 0.8f);
        while((y2 = randPos.nextFloat()) < 0.8f);
        if(randPos.nextInt() % 2 == 0)
            y2 *= -1;
        physicsHandler.setVelocity( x2*40,  y2*40);
        this.prevX = this.mX;
        this.prevY = this.mY;
    }
    else if(this.mY < 0){
        this.move++;
        float x2,y2;
        while((x2 = randPos.nextFloat()) < 0.8f);
        while((y2 = randPos.nextFloat()) < 0.8f);
        if(randPos.nextInt() % 2 == 0)
            x2 *= -1;
        physicsHandler.setVelocity( x2*40,  y2*40);
        this.prevX = this.mX;
        this.prevY = this.mY;
    }
    else if(this.mX > (MainActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH - MainActivity.MONSTER_WIDTH)){
        this.move++;
        float x2,y2;
        while((x2 = randPos.nextFloat()) < 0.8f);
        while((y2 = randPos.nextFloat()) < 0.8f);
        x2 *= -1;
        if(randPos.nextInt() % 2 == 0)
            y2 *= -1;
        physicsHandler.setVelocity( x2*40,  y2*40);
        this.prevX = this.mX;
        this.prevY = this.mY;
    }
    else if(this.mY > (MainActivity.CAMERA_HEIGHT - MainActivity.MONSTER_HEIGHT)){
        this.move++;
        float x2,y2;
        while((x2 = randPos.nextFloat()) < 0.8f);
        while((y2 = randPos.nextFloat()) < 0.8f);
        if(randPos.nextInt() % 2 == 0)
            x2 *= -1;
        y2 *= -1;
        physicsHandler.setVelocity( x2*40,  y2*40);
        this.prevX = this.mX;
        this.prevY = this.mY;
    }


    for(int i=0 ; i < MainActivity.playerSprite.size(); i++){

        if(( MainActivity.playerSprite.get(i)).collidesWith(this) || this.collidesWith(MainActivity.playerSprite.get(i))){

            float x2, y2;
            while((x2 = randPos.nextFloat()) < 0.8f);
            while((y2 = randPos.nextFloat()) < 0.8f);

            if(randPos.nextInt() % 2 == 0)
                x2 *= -1;
            if(randPos.nextInt() % 2 == 0)
                y2 *= -1;

            this.physicsHandler.setVelocity( x2*100,  y2*100);
            break;
        }
    }   
    super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to put your code after the `super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);` ?